# Get minimum and maximum Latitude and Longitude of New York?

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, google-maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

How can I find the minimum and maximum Latitude and Longitude of New York?

I need the coordinates of New York limits, in order to crop the area of the map outside of New York.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a website called "Map Developers" that provide some tools using Google Maps.  One of their tools is a bounding-box tool:

> Show a bounding box around a city, state, country, or zipcode using geocoding

Entering the name of a city, state, or address will bring up the bounding box with North & South Latitude and East & West Longitude coordinates.

You can access this tool at [Map Developers - Bounding Box](https://www.mapdevelopers.com/geocode_bounding_box.php)